# Laravel 5.6, no guarda en base de datos y no muestra ningún error en consola del navegador

Tags: laravel, vue.js, mariadb

de antemano gracias por contestar, 
Utilizando Laravel 5.6 y Vue2 y ya probado con otros componentes la conexión y guardado de base de datos, no me guarda con un controlador en especial y no me muestra algún error como para buscar, leer o investigar.

1. La función en la vista, función validar no tiene problema

```php
            registrarHc(){
                if(this.validarHc()){
                    return;
                }
                let me = this;
                axios.post('/hc/registrar', {
                    'paciente_id': this.paciente_id,
                    'tipo': this.tipo,
                    'motivo_consulta': this.motivo_consulta,
                    'ant_patologicos': this.ant_patologicos,
                    'ant_quirurgicos': this.ant_quirurgicos,
                    'ant_alergicos': this.ant_alergicos,
                    'ant_toxicos': this.ant_toxicos,
                    'ant_farmacologicos': this.ant_farmacologicos,
                    'ant_familiares': this.ant_familiares,
                    'data': this.arrayDetalle
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    me.listado=1;
                    //me.buscar=this.identificacion;
                    me.listarHc(1,'','identificacion');
                    me.paciente_id=0;
                    me.tipo='';
                    me.motivo_consulta='';
                    me.ant_patologicos='';
                    me.ant_quirurgicos='';
                    me.ant_alergicos='';
                    me.ant_toxicos='';
                    me.ant_toxicos='';
                    me.ant_farmacologicos='';
                    me.ant_familiares='';
                    me.opcion_id=0;
                    me.opcion='';
                    me.arrayDetalle=[];
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
```

2. Controlador

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $mytime= Carbon::now('America/Bogota');
            //echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();

            $hc = new HistoriaClinica();
            $hc->paciente_id = $request->paciente_id;
            $hc->tipo = $request->tipo;
            $hc->motivo_consulta = $request->motivo_consulta;
            $hc->fecha_hc = $mytime->toDateTimeString();
            $hc->usuario_id = \Auth::user()->id;
            $hc->estado = 'Guardada';
            $hc->save();

            $paciente= Paciente::FindOrFail($request->paciente_id);
            $paciente->ant_patologicos = $request->ant_patologicos;
            $paciente->ant_quirurgicos = $request->ant_quirurgicos;
            $paciente->ant_alergicos = $request->ant_alergicos;
            $paciente->ant_toxicos = $request->ant_toxicos;
            $paciente->ant_farmacologicos = $request->ant_farmacologicos;
            $paciente->ant_familiares = $request->ant_familiares;
            $paciente->save();

            $detalles= $request->data; //Array
            foreach($detalles as $ep=>$det){
                $detalle = new DetalleHc();
                $detalle->hc_id = $hc->id;
                $detalle->opcion_id = $det['opcion_id'];
                $detalle->detalle = $det['detalle'];
                $detalle->observacion = $det['observacion'];
                $detalle->save();
            }

        } catch (Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }
```

por favor indicarme que puede estar mal, porque no me guarda en la base de datos, ya verifique tipo de datos de las relaciones y los campos y están bien.
Hay alguna forma de ver o como depurar en estos casos.
gracias nuevamente

Comment: Has verificado si ingresa por acá? `} catch (Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
        }`

Comment: No imprime nada } catch (Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack(); 
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"guardada\");</script>"; 
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está faltando el `commit()`. Cuando iniciás una transaction de forma manual, para que los cambios impacten sobre la DB, tenés que hacer un `DB::commit()`.

Agregalo al final de tu `try`, después del `foreach()`.

[Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions).

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por contestar. Me falto leer un poco mas en la documentación

Answer (score 0):

prueba a revisar la estructura, debe quedar como esta:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    ...
    $hc->save();
    ...
    $paciente->save();
    ...
    foreach(){
        ...
        $detalle->save();
    }

    DB::commit();
    // todo correcto
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // algo salió mal
}
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por contestar. Me falto leer un poco mas en la documentación